# Exactly counting number of vertices of a polyhedron

Tags: convex-geometry, polyhedra

Suppose $Ax\leq b$ is a polyhedron, where the number of rows in $A$ is $r$, the vector $x$ lies in $\mathbb R^n$ and the rank of $A$ is $t$. Assume minimal number of hyperplane inequalities to define the polyhedron is $r'$.

> **Question.** Can we exactly count the number of vertices in the polyhedron? If so, how to count it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer varies according to the structure of the polytope. If you want the answer in particular cases, you can use vertex enumeration software, such as [lrs](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Eavis/C/lrs.html) .

Comment: I provided update.

Comment: My answer is the same.  The number of vertices is not a function of $n,r,t,r'$ even in 3-d.

Comment: Can you please provide an example pairing to illustrate?

Comment: Make a square pyramid using 5 planes. It has 5 vertices. If you cut off the apex with an extra plane you get 8 vertices, but if you cut off one of the corners of the base you get 7 vertices.

Comment: It's not my field of expertise, sorry.